# Crystal Report Entire Row height increase

Tags: crystal-reports

(Broken image was here)

The growth increases the height of the one row column but it doesn't increase the height of the entire row. i have checked and it can grow for all the fields, one of the field has been  greyed out and cannot be checked. The "keep object together" box is checked in the format field properties of the field. I checked and the "Keep Together" field was checked inthe field properties and in the section expert. i tried all different ways,and don't know what kind of formula I would use to get the whole row growth while at least one field height increases in a row.

Comment: I don't see any image.  Do you have multiple rows in a single detail section, however?  Is that the issue?

Comment: sorry! I was not able to attach the image the site did not able as i am a new user.i have only one row in the detail section of designer. i have lla rows set to can grow but on increse of height of one field in the row the entire row dosent increase in height.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I think without a picture I'm not going to be of much help.  If a row is set to `Can Grow`, the entire row should grow as well, so I'm not sure why the rows aren't increasing in height in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by using boxes and lines instead of fixed borders around the fields. 

Place a box around your fields spanning the header and details sections then right click and format box. Tick/check 'Extend to bottom of section when printing'. 

Place separator lines vertically between each field making sure they touch the top of the box (don't worry about touching the bottom). Now right click each vertical line and format line.
Tick/check 'Extend to bottom of section when printing'. 

Now when your can grow field is more than 1 line the fields will appear to have borders as you wish! - 

For More Reference - Click [here](http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?t=96790&sid=1308037c515ef175d966fc14e79d0a3c)

 
 

Another reason for no increase in height of whole row when one column/field value grows is that..a fixed horizontal separator line would be just touching the details field. Make sure if there is any horizontal separator line added by you then it should be aloof from the fields added. (i.e, Clearance Margin must be there between the line and the data field column added).

This solution worked for me big time :)